# componentDidUpdate gives RCTDeviceEventEmitter error when doing network request

Tags: react-native

My app has a component that is updated every time the user swipe it.
That component gets new props every time and it's values are updated accordingly.
With the new data received, I create a facebook graph api fetch request to get the user's profile image.
To make it look better, I added a default image until the fetch request finishes. I reset the image to default in `componentWillReceiveProps`.
The error I get is "Error calling function: RCTDeviceEventEmitter:emit"
It only happanes when I am not remotely debugging (using the chrome debugger of react native).
This is the relevant code:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    var temp;
    temp=this.state.profileInfo;
    temp.image='http://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.roosterteeth.com/default/tb/user_profile_female.jpg';
    this.setState({
      profileInfo:temp,
    });
  },
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevProps!=this.props){
      console.log("Updated!!!");
      var api = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + this.props.owner_id +
                     '/picture?type=normal&access_token=' + this.props.credentials.token;
      fetch(api)
            .then((response) =>{
              var temp;
              temp=this.state.profileInfo;
              temp.image=response.url;
              this.setState({
                profileInfo:temp,
              });
            })
            .done();
    }
  },
  componentDidMount(){
    var api = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + this.props.owner_id +
                   '/picture?type=normal&access_token=' + this.props.credentials.token;
    fetch(api)
          .then((response) =>{
            var temp;
            temp=this.state.profileInfo;
            temp.image=response.url;
            this.setState({
              profileInfo:temp,
            });
          })
          .done();
  },
```

Does anybody know how can I resolve this error? Why is it only when not debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11764](http://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11764). Someone opened the same issue with as little as code possible, so this may mean that the problem is not with your React component.

Anyway you can remove componentDidUpdate method at all like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  var temp;
  temp=this.state.profileInfo;
  temp.image='http://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.roosterteeth.com/default/tb/user_profile_female.jpg';
  this.setState({
    profileInfo:temp,
  }, () => {
    if(nextProps!=this.props) {
      console.log("Updated!!!");

      var api = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + nextProps.owner_id +
        '/picture?type=normal&access_token=' + nextProps.credentials.token;
      fetch(api)
        .then((response) => {
          var temp;
          temp = this.state.profileInfo;
          temp.image = response.url;
          this.setState({
            profileInfo: temp,
          });
        })
        .done();
    }
  });
},
componentDidMount(){
  var api = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + this.props.owner_id +
    '/picture?type=normal&access_token=' + this.props.credentials.token;
  fetch(api)
    .then((response) =>{
      var temp;
      temp=this.state.profileInfo;
      temp.image=response.url;
      this.setState({
        profileInfo:temp,
      });
    })
    .done();
},
```

Comment: The error is gone, but it does not work. `if(nextProps!=this.props)` is always false and I never update the picture. When I look at the log holding the current and previous props, they are not the same.  Do you know why?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is called every time new props are received. `nextProps!=this.props` actually should always return true(not sure why you are getting false). So to check if props changed, either we should check properties of props one by one (like this: if(nextProps.owner_id!=this.props.owner_id)) or do a deep comparison. In your case, if you want to re-fetch results every time you can remove  `if(nextProps!=this.props)`.

Comment: I removed the condition and now I get the same error when not in debug mode.

Comment: Then it means that the problem might not be related to your particular component.